# How to load SQL data into the Hortonworks?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, odbc, hortonworks-data-platform

I have Installed Hortonworks SandBox in my pc. also tried with a CSV file and its getting in a table structerd manner its OK (Hive + Hadoop), nw I want to migrate my current SQL Databse into Sandbox (MS SQL 2008 r2).How I will do this? Also want to connect to my project (VS 2010 C#).

Is it possible to connect through ODBC?

I Heard sqoop is using for transferring data from SQL to Hadoop so how I can do this migration with sqoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own job to migrate the data. But Sqoop would be more convenient. To do that you have to [download](http://apache.osuosl.org/sqoop/1.4.3/sqoop-1.4.3.tar.gz) Sqoop and the appropriate connector, Microsoft SQL Server Connector for Apache Hadoop in your case. You can download it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27584).Please go through the [Sqoop user guide](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html). It contains all the information in proper detail.

And Hive does support ODBC. You can find more on this at this [page](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/hiveodbc.html).

Comment: You can try Teland as well

Answer (score 1):

I wrote down the steps you need to go through in the Hortonworks Sandbox to install the JDBC driver and get it to work: http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/import-microsoft-sql-data-into-sandbox/

To connect to Hadoop in your C# project you can use the Hortonworks Hive ODBC driver from http://hortonworks.com/thankyou-hdp13/#addon-table. Read the PDF (which is also on that page) to see how it works (I used *Hive Server Type 2* with user name *sandbox*)

Comment: In the current sandbox there is no /usr/lib/sqoop dir @kloarubeek. Should I create it or create a lib folder inside the /home/sqoop dir?

Comment: How to find current path solution: http://de.hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/hdp-2-2-sandbox-could-not-find-sqoop-folder/