# Java - com.cloudera.sqoop vs. org.apache.sqoop which to import from sqoop jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, cloudera, sqoop

I am confused While import library (com.cloudera.sqoop and org.apache.sqoop)  and get this in eclipse (jar included [sqoop-1.4.4-hadoop200.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsqoop144hadoop200jar.htm) ) -

The method run(com.cloudera.sqoop.SqoopOptions) in the type ImportTool is not applicable for the arguments 
 (org.apache.sqoop.SqoopOptions) with this two line (option parameter are added between this two lines)

```
 SqoopOptions options = new SqoopOptions();
 int ret = new ImportTool().run(options);
```

If I choose Cloudera method get deprecated but if I choose apache then run method doesn't accept the options argument. Here are the screenshots.

[image: Import com.cloudera.sqoop]
[image: Import org.apache.sqoop]

This is also related to my question I asked earlier (
[Java - MySQL to Hive Import where MySQL Running on Windows and Hive Running on Cent OS (Horton Sandbox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351849/java-mysql-to-hive-import-where-mysql-running-on-windows-and-hive-running-on-c/)).

Comment: I would use the one from Apache.. deprecated methods should be avoided as far as possible.. Check whether both (deprecated and the one within apache) do the same thing.. check their implementation and then see what arguments to pass..

Comment: I am passing the SqoopOptions Object as parameter. Implementation also want that object. But I dont know why it is showing error and forcing me to include cloudera.sqoop.SqoopOptions :(

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be many changes between the two SqoopOptions implementations. You can view the diff here..

http://www.diffchecker.com/n342v2f6

I would suggest using the Cloudera SqoopOptions class with the apache ImportTool found at 'org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool' directory, cause it accepts it and has most of the options available.